# What does it mean abstract type when we say it to a binary heap tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I read a term abstract type which mean you can use the structure or the skeleton. I am talking about binary heap tree . I read it's a abstract type but when question arises what will be the time complexity to merge two min heap to create a max heap ?
I got some answers saying copy elements of trees into array and the use build heap method n create max heap in O(n) time ! But how will you copy elements of min heap in const time/or in O(n) time when you can't traverse the tree as its a abstract type. The only thing left with you is delete all element one by one n keep it in array Which will take O(nlogn) time.
Could anyone put some time to make me understand this doubt ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the implementation of an abstract data type with its interface.

To implement an Heap (or Queue, etc) you can do whatever you want with its internal structure.
Note that the internal structure of an Heap could be anything (array, list...); in fact the internal structure of the Heap is hidden to the user (but again: it is visible to the developer).

The implemented Heap will offer only its interface method which define his abstract type.

When people talk about merging two heaps, they are talking about an heap that implements also the merge function. Inside the merge function (within the implementation of the heap) you can use all the function of the internal implementation.

Comment: ya...i got it will provide only its interface. But via that interface can you traverse it ? Take a situation : Get the 2nd min from a min heap ?
I hope you will answer it as delete the root, heapify, get the root and thats your 2nd min,right ? ( & it will take O(logn) time)
Why would i delete the root if i can traverse the tree i.e 2nd min would surely be in level next of root. (here i need only 2 comparison i.e between left n right of root, less than O(logn) time agree??)
Could you please correct me if am going wrong ?

Comment: "traverse" is not an available interface operation.